# Where did the 3 dot 'user is typing' feedback you see on messenger apps originate?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, chat, typing

I've noticed a lot of messenger apps such as HipChat and Facebook Messenger have implemented a horizontal 3 dot icon which signifies a user is typing.

[image: Screenshot showing the three dots]

I'm curious to know how this icon came about and what the history/thought process behind it might be?

Comment: Are you looking for the history/thought process on the ellipse (`...`) or the idea of showing an icon of some type while another user is typing?

Comment: Hangouts has this too

Comment: Which app first used an ellipsis icon for this purpose? It's much cuter than its verbose forebear *Your contact is typing...*

Comment: talk(1) shows other end typing in real time maybe one day 1990 technology will come to messenger :)

Comment: Please remember that there is a [Unicode codepoint for the horizontal ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis#Computer_representations) (U+2026, "`…`") that should be used instead of the three consecutive full stops ("`...`") that everyone in this thread has been using so far.

Comment: @n.st it's kind of harder to animate single character than 3 dots...

Comment: I would disagree with many of the answers here; I don't really think it's an ellipsis.  It's animated, so it's just like any other loading animation such as any of these [loading animations](http://www.opengraphicdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/ajax-loading-animated-graphics.jpg)

Answer (score 86):

The three dot symbol is called an 'ellipsis' and has been [used in text since at least 1588](http://www.cam.ac.uk/research/features/dot-dot-dot-how-the-ellipsis-made-its-mark)

Originally it signified a pause or tailing off in speech but, in modern times, it also signifies and implied continuance of any textual content. An example of the modern usage might be in webpages where you sometimes find "More after the jump..." meaning that an article will be continued after clicking a link.

Both the original (pause) and modern (continuance) meanings are relevant here as that is exactly what's happening when your friend is typing their reply to you via your IM.

Comment: I'm gonna start feeling really old if it turns out people don't learn what an ellipses is in school anymore...

Comment: I'm convinced people don't learn in school any more at all.

Comment: @WorseDoughnut I've heard of kids seeing a 1.44" floppy and saying "oh cool, you 3D printed the save icon". :-p

Comment: 1.44" floppy disk?

Comment: @ceejayoz That's an extremely small floppy...

Comment: 1.44mb perhaps? :)

Comment: @HasanSahoglu That's it! Whoops. :-p

Comment: the three dots are animated in the chat scenarios from the question and they are much larger and bolder than the fonts themselves so it's possible some users don't interpret them as the standard continuation marker. I can see how that would make someone raise this questions in the first place but I agree with your answer

Comment: @WorseDoughnut - I was born in '81, and the first time I ever heard it referred to as an ellipsis was about 6 years ago when I was learning how to do something in Java and the instructions I was following said to "click on the ellipsis"...  I had no idea what that was.

Comment: @Taegost which (unless you are from a non-english speaking country and new the symbol in your native language) is just a damning indictment of the responsible school system.

Comment: @WorseDoughnut I'm 17 still in school and no... They do not teach this in school anymore. First time I seen was in a book I read about 6 years ago.

Comment: First time I heard it called ellipsis I started looking around for ovals.  Math was a far more interesting class for me than English.

Comment: An ellipsis can also signify a placeholder for additional (usually omitted) text, which also fits the user-is-typing use.

Comment: @DRF - I'm in the US...  The saddest thing is that the middle school I went to (where I'd expect to learn it) was in the top 25 in the country at the time...

Comment: @WorseDoughnut https://youtu.be/JW7CNba_dFI?t=75

Answer (score 54):

**MSN Messenger Service**

> How do you feel about the typing indicator—“David is typing”—that
>   appears on your buddy’s screen while you’re composing a message in
>   chat? Does it make you feel self-conscious about how long you’re
>   taking to write a message? Do you hate it when you are multitasking and your erstwhile best friend keeps sending messages like “Are you still there? What are you doing? Do you still like me? Have I fallen in your heart?”
>
> If so, you have me to blame, **because I was one of the people who
>   invented the damn thing**. But I can explain everything...

[I Built That “So-and-So Is Typing” Feature in Chat](http://www.slate.com/articles/technology/bitwise/2014/02/typing_indicator_in_chat_i_built_it_and_i_m_not_sorry.html)

Comment: Nice find. To supplement the answer there's an article here: http://www.nytimes.com/2014/08/31/fashion/texting-anxiety-caused-by-little-bubbles.html?_r=0 which claims that Blackberry BBM was the first chat app to bring the feature to mobile - but doesn't specific why the icon used are dots rather than text.

Comment: MSN/WLM *never* had an ellipsis, animated or otherwise, for the typing indicator. That article is about the feature in general, not the icon (and in fact it makes no mention of iconography whatsoever).

Comment: @BoltClock is right. While info here is interesting, the actual answer is provided by Andrew

Comment: @BoltClock The question is about knowing the thought process behind it " I'm curious to know how this icon came about and what the history/thought process behind it might be?"

Comment: @Dipak: The thought process behind the *icon*, not the *feature*. It's even in your quote. Like I said, MSN/WLM never had an icon for the typing indicator - it simply printed "[contact name] is writing a message." in the status bar. This was true for *all* versions, including the original Windows Messenger. Icons weren't in use until Skype (which appeared a couple of years later), and even then 1) it wasn't an ellipsis, and 2) the icon that it used was also accompanied by text.

Comment: If any thought went into iconography at all at the time, the original creator must have decided it wasn't a good idea or it wasn't technically feasible. But he doesn't even *mention* it, so for all we know he never even considered it to begin with. Even in the article it says "David is typing", it doesn't say "those three dots in a speech bubble" or something.

Comment: As said by others, OP is asking about the *icon* not the *feature*. But I wouldn't downvote (even if I had enough rep), as this is still a nice find.

Comment: Nice ytalk reference.  I miss chatting through a ytalk-like interface.

Comment: Hmmm... pretty sure [ICQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICQ) predates MSN Messenger.  I remember chatting on it and being able to tell when users were typing...

Comment: @DanEsparza yeah I recall ICQ having this way before MSN...

Answer (score 4):

The other answers have explained (excellently!) the origin of the ellipsis symbol, and how older chat programs displayed typing indicators. However, this doesn't directly answer the question.

To my knowledge, the first mobile app use of the "three dots in a bubble" indicator is [iMessage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMessage). As Samuel pointed out in his comment, this was taken from iChat on the desktop, which had this UI as early as 2005.

When iMessage launched, the "typing" indicator (and read receipts) was a big differentiator from SMS. A lot of other mobile apps have since copied the typing bubble UI, even though desktop chat apps have had these types of indicators for a while.

Comment: this is the best answer so far - personally have not seen this icon until facebook started using it recently, yet iMessage has had it since late 2011

Comment: iChat, the predecessor to iMessage, had the three dots as well, as far back as 2005; maybe earlier. Source: http://www.cocoaforge.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=1668

Comment: @Samuel: Cool, I didn't realize that!

Answer (score 3):

I would think it is based on the [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis), which, according to Wikipedia, is a punctuation mark indicating: "[…] an unfinished thought, a leading statement, a slight pause […]".

When you see an ellipsis in a sentence, you know the sentence is not (yet) finished. When you are in a written conversation, it seems the best representation of: my sentence is not yet finished.

Comment: Could you find any references for this? Its a logical assumption but at the moment just speculation

Comment: Yes, it is my assumption at this point in time. Looking for references, though.

Comment: Still no definitive reference, I'm afraid...

Comment: Note that you used ellipses in your answer in yet another way, which is to be a placeholder for omitted text.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the use of the ellipsis in modern messaging apps derives from its use in some Internet chatrooms of the mid-to-late 90s. I can recall myself and others, when in essentially one-on-one conversations with other chatroom patrons, sometimes responding to the other person's statement first with simply "..." and then with an actual sentence.

Why did we do this? I can't speak for others but I remember that when I used "..." in chatrooms I meant it to convey a befuddled snarkiness, rather than a "Please Wait" prompt, because I didn't like what the other person said and I was a brat. So perhaps we should interpret it in modern messaging apps as an implicit "Bite Me" from the other person. ;D

But perhaps some of the young people that frequented these chatrooms at that time simply took the "..." to mean "Please Wait" and then grew up to become software engineers that worked on the messaging apps that use "..." as we see it today.

Comment: I also used this in chat rooms, but I sued it to mean "hang on, it's a long response and I'm going to take a while to type it up"